# gram-schmidt process and notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand the gram-schmidt process notation. My book uses a lot of abbreviations and skips the simple steps.

```
<v2,v1>=<x2 - <x2,v1>/||v1||^2 * v1, v1 >
```

Why does it switch from x's to v's? What does this mean `<x2,v1>`? What does this mean v1, v1? This is really the only thing I recognize.

Could I please have a detailed explanation with these two vectors?

\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 2\\ 3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 1\\-1
\end{bmatrix}

This is the only step I am familiar with.

1^2+2^2+3^2=14

Comment: And unfortunately, even this step is wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

The $x_i$ are the initial vectors and the $v_i$ are those of the orthogonal basis to be constructed.

The trick is to consider every $x_i$ in turn and make it orthogonal to the $v_k$ already computed ($k<i$). You make a vector orthogonal to another by subtracting its orthogonal projection on the latter. The orthogonal projection is obtained by means of the scalar product.

Indeed, assume we want to make $x_i$ orthogonal to some $v_k$, i.e. find $x'_i$ such that $$<x'_i,v_k>=0$$ (angle brackets denote the dot product). We try a modified vector

$$x'_i=x_i+\lambda v_k.$$

Then

$$<x'_i,v_k>=<x_i,v_k>+\lambda <v_k,v_k>=0$$ giving

$$\lambda=-\frac{<x_i,v_k>}{<v_k,v_k>}$$ and

$$x'_i=x_i-\frac{<x_i,v_k>}{<v_k,v_k>}v_k.$$

This operation can be iterated with all $v_k$, in any order, because thanks to the orthogonality of the $v_k$, making $x_i$ orthogonal to $v_{k'}$ after $v_k$ does not destroy orthogonality to $v_k$. In the end, $x'_i$ can become a new $v_i$.